# .exe is not created when using launch4j and maven

Tags: java, maven, exe, launch4j

I'm trying to create an exe file for my **JAVA** project using **launch4j** and **Maven**.

Here is my **pom.xml**

```
 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptortRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptortRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>dev.main.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest> 
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>dev.main.App</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>l4j-clui</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <headerType>console</headerType>
                        <jar>${project.build.directory}/target/App-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
                        <outfile>${project.build.directory}/target/App.exe</outfile>
                        <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>dev.main.App</mainClass>
                        </classPath>
                        <jre>
                            <minVersion>1.6.0</minVersion>
                            <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                        </jre>
                        <versionInfo>
                            <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                            <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                            <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                            <copyright>C</copyright>
                            <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
                            <txtProductVersion>1.0.0.0</txtProductVersion>
                            <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                            <internalName>AppName</internalName>
                            <originalFilename>App.exe</originalFilename>
                        </versionInfo>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I run : `mvn clean compile assembly:single` to create my **jar** app with all Maven dependencies.

To create the **.exe** I do  : `mvn package` but nothing is created under target folder.

Am I missing a goal or a configuration ?

Ismail

Comment: Does `mvn package:launch4j` do anything for you?

Comment: I tried `mvn package:laucn4j`but I got a `BUILD FAILURE` with this message : `No plugin found for prefix package in the current project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not an expert on maven, but the `<pluginManagement>` tag looks fishy to me. When I get the [Maven POM documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) right, you want a plain `<plugins>` Element.

Comment: Could you please help me with this new issue here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425547/use-launch4j-with-maven-in-jenkins-as-maven-goal-on-a-linux-64-bit